# IIS 8.5 Classic ASP and 500 Error

Tags: iis-8.5

I am getting following error when I run classic Asp page on IIS

```
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.
```

I tried to the following settings, but still I am not able to see Actual code error

[image]

```
<%
Set cdoConfig = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

With cdoConfig.Fields
.Item(cdoSendUsingMethod) = cdoSendUsingPort
.Item(cdoSMTPServer) = "IP ADDRESS"
.Update
End With

Set cdoMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")

With cdoMessage
Set .Configuration = cdoConfig
.From = "test@test.com"
.To = "test@test.com"
.Subject = "Sample CDO Message"
.TextBody = "This is a test for CDO.message"
.Send
End With

Set cdoMessage = Nothing
Set cdoConfig = Nothing
%>
```

Comment: This is the actual error being returned to the browser.  "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred."   If you changed the "Send Errors To Browser" to "False" it would return nothing at all.

Answer (score 1):

In Error Pages Settings you can set how you want to display errors:

[image]